# Calling functions in an async function javascript (Meteor) Getting undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, meteor

The issue seems to be that calling the function `vote_ipcheck()` and `vote_cookie_check()` both are throwing an error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`. If I put the contents of the function inside the `$.getJSON call` then it's not an issue, however calling the function throws that error.

If anyone's got an idea as to why something like this is occurring, it would be great.

```
    if (ip_check) {
        $.getJSON("http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=?", function(data){

            console.log(data.host);

            var vote_ipcheck = vote_ipcheck(data.host);
            var vote_cookie_check = vote_cookie_check();

            if (vote_ipcheck && vote_cookie_check) {
                Router.go('pollyResults', {_id: id});
            } else if (vote_ipcheck == false && vote_cookie_check == false) {
                update_poll();
            }

        });
    }

    function vote_cookie_check() {
      // Handling the cookie business
      console.log(ReactiveCookie.list());

      if (ReactiveCookie.get('voted')) {
        var object_voted = JSON.parse(ReactiveCookie.get('voted'));
        if (id in object_voted) {
            if (object_voted[id] == true) {
                    return true;
            }
        } else {
            object_voted[id] = true;
            ReactiveCookie.set('voted', JSON.stringify(object_voted), {days: 365});
            return false;
        }
      } else {
            var object_voted = {};
            object_voted[id] = true;
            ReactiveCookie.set('voted', JSON.stringify(object_voted), {days: 365});
            return false;
      }
    }

    function vote_ipcheck(ip) {
        ip_voted = ip_array.indexOf(ip);

        if (ip_voted > -1) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            Polls.update({_id: id}, {$push : {already_voted : ip}});
            return false;           
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can try writing them in async style by providing callbacks and see if they work then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not redefine `vote_ipcheck` and `vote_cookie_check` in the local scope if you want to use global functions with these names. Give the local variables different names.

```
        var ipcheck = vote_ipcheck(data.host);
        var cookie_check = vote_cookie_check();

        if (ipcheck && cookie_check) {
            Router.go('pollyResults', {_id: id});
        } else if (ipcheck == false && cookie_check == false) {
            update_poll();
        }
```

Comment: Seems to work properly, didn't notice that function names and variable names conflict in javascript. Thanks.